# Google Vision Text Detection returns too much unnecesary data

Tags: api, ocr, google-vision

When using Google Vision to run text detection on a menu, the response from their API is way too large and returns way too much data that I don't need. I just want the text from the menu, not all the coordinates that come with the response. I can't find anything about narrowing down the response in any documentation i've read. Does someone know how to specify what fields get returned in the response?

Heres my request:

```
POST: https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<MY_KEY>

BODY:

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "content": "...base64-encoded-image-content..."
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is it too much overhead to just parse the JSON and extract the fullTextAnnotation. text out of that? Those JSON responses usually don't have a large size. Your own answer to this question is the only way that I know of to narrow down the data in the response, but it feels prone to failure - this is an undocumented part of their API so Google can alter it on the spot. It really depends on your use case, but I would not use it in the release version.

Comment: @CosminCretu I actually did end up finding docs on it. I just had to search for "Google API fields parameter" not "Google Vision API fields parameter" which is pretty annoying...

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance#partial

And yes it would have been a lot of overhead to parse all that data with the 100's of needless x,y coordinates it was returning

Comment: That's a great link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. I could not find any documentation on how to do this, I had to just guess for like half an hour. If someone knows of any documentation on this let me know.

Anyway you can use the "fields" parameter to narrow down the response like so:

```
POST: https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<MY_KEY>&fields=responses.fullTextAnnotation.text
```

This will only return the menu text from the Google Vision text detection API